# Configurable Backbone.js events selectors

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm working on simple application with excelent framework Backbone.js and it will be nice if I could make configurable backbone view events selector for example this way it doesn't work, cause it's wrong js syntax:

```
return Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click ' + someConfigSelector: 'doSomethink'
    }
})
```

Is there any other way to setup events in Backbone views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phoenecke/hyLMz/1/

You can use a function for `events` instead of an object.

```
return Backbone.View.extend({
    events: function() {
        // add some normal events to the hash
        var e = {
            'click #foo': 'doSomething1',
            'click #bar': 'doSomething2'
        };
        // add one where key is calculated
        e['click ' + someConfigSelector] = 'doSomething';
        // return events hash
        return e;
    }
});
```

That way, you can add your events where the key is calculated based on your config.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the method below for dynamic events, as this function will be called any time `delegateEvent` is called.

Per the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) on delegateEvent, which is called after the view's `initialize` function is executed, you can use this technique to create the events dynamically:

```
var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    events: function () {
        var evt = {};
        evt['click ' + this._extraSelector] = '_onButtonClick';
        return evt;
    },
    initialize: function(config) {
        // passed in the selector, or defaulted 
        this._extraSelector = config.extraSelector || "BUTTON.default";
    }, 

    _onButtonClick: function() { }
});

var v = new TestView({ extraSelector: 'BUTTON.sample' });
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not seem to work anymore as of Nov 2015, since delegateEvents() is called before initialize() during view initialization. Need to call this.delegateEvents(); inside initialize() one more time for it to pickup the value of config.extraSelector.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
return Backbone.View.extend({
    events: { },

    initialize:function() {
        this.events['click ' + someConfigSelector] = 'doSomethink';
    }
})
```

But it somewhat breaks the convention of how events are declared in backbone and makes the code harder to read. Perhaps someone has a better approach.